# Ruby running two scripts with mulithreading

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, rubygems, sinatra

So I'm trying to have my ruby (no rails) application be run with a single call from the terminal i.e. '**ruby run.rb**'. However I have two scripts that need to be run, **app.rb** and **app2.rb**, the issue is, both these scripts don't finish - they keep on being run so as to keep the system running, this means that one of the scripts never gets run - it calls the first script (app.rb) and never the second (app2.rb) these scripts need to be run concurrently!

It does work when I open another command line and just run one script in each however.

I have tried:

```
def runApp
    system("ruby app.rb")
end
def runApp2
    system("ruby app2.rb")
end
t1 = Thread.new{runApp()}
t2 = Thread.new{runApp2()}
t1.join
t2.join
```

However this will only run the first thread (the one running app.rb) because this is being constantly run. Any ideas how it can also run the second thread concurrently?

:EDIT: One of the scripts is using the **Sinatra gem**, the other also calls one of its functions every ten seconds.

Comment: Which Ruby implementation are you using? Rubinius, MagLev, IronRuby, JRuby, XRuby, and Topaz can run multiple threads in parallel, but for example YARV cannot. (I'm not sure about MRuby and Opal, although I guess Opal cannot.)

Comment: Just using vanilla ruby, I am using the Sinatra gem in one of the scripts however

Comment: What do you mean by "vanilla Ruby"? Ruby is a programming language, the Ruby Language Specification doesn't say anything about whether threads are executed in parallel or not. That is dependent on the specific implementation you are using. If you want threads to run in parallel, you need to use an implementation that can run threads in parallel. Almost all *can* run threads in parallel, but if you use one of the few ones that cannot, then you will have to find a different solution, such as using processes instead of threads.

Comment: What you use inside those programs is completely irrelevant. They are just shell processes in this context. They could be Haskell or COBOL, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Throughout this project other tasks can be threaded and do run in parallel so I'm not running an implementation of ruby that doesn't support multi threading. This is what I meant by vanilla, saying the implementation isn't anything special enough to change whether or not tasks can be multithreaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one possible solution I've found is

`system("ruby app.rb & ruby app2.rb")`

This only works however if running from linux I think however so I would still appreciate any further solutions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html) you can do it like this:

```
threads = []
threads << Thread.new{runApp()}
threads << Thread.new{runApp2()}

threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

I guess this works because `each` is parallel.